# What should i do to control and manage devices and users through internet?

Tags: cloud, iot

I have wifi modules (ESP8266), which are not in the same location.
I set one of them as a server and connected to internet by using No-IP service. (It's same as a server).

Now, i want to:

- Control devices
- Devices monitoring
- Save data.
  Controlling will be done by multiple users.
  I am a beginner and want to develop a server to do this it seems hardly with me (protocols,....). 
   Eclipse IoT has many frameworks but i don't know where to start.
   Which framework could i begin with?

Comment: Want to use a esp8266 as a server?

Comment: I just do it - (make esp8266 as a server and control it), my question seems not clearly. I'm sorry about that. 
I want to know which framework could help me build back-end server to control many my devices (current only one device if using esp8266 as a server).

Now, i use **firebase DB** to control my devices. No need own back-end server anymore. Thank you.

Comment: Tried [Cayenne](https://mydevices.com/) or [Blynk](http://www.blynk.cc/) ?

Comment: I'll try. Thanks, cagdas.